# Adding ID based on innerHTML to all elements in class

Tags: javascript

I need to write a code to add IDs to all element in one class. The IDs have to be based on innerText.

Elements look like that:

```
<lable class="sf-label-radio">Name1<span>Some Other Text that I do not need</span><label>
<lable class="sf-label-radio">Name2<span>Some Other Text that I do not need</span><label>
```

etc.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
addIDtoGI();
function addIDtoGI() {
    let searchButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('sf-label-radio');
    
    for(i = 0; i < searchButtons.length; i++) {
        x = searchButtons[i].innerHTML;
        x = x.substr(0, x.search("<")).replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        x = onlyEngLetters(x);
        searchButtons[i].setAttribute('id',x);
    }
}
    
function onlyEngLetters(text) {
  text=text.replace("ę","e");
  text=text.replace("ó","o");
  text=text.replace("ą","a");
  text=text.replace("ś","s");
  text=text.replace("ł","l");
  text=text.replace("ż","z");
  text=text.replace("ź","z");
  text=text.replace("ć","c");
  text=text.replace("ń","n");
  return text;
}
</script>
```

Thank You for help!

Comment: what is `lable`. Isn't this should be `label`.

Comment: The value of the `id` attribute must not contain white-space characters.

Comment: `lable` doesn't exist, it's `label`. `lable` doesn't have closing tag. `lenght` doesn't exist, it's `length`. `id` has to be unique. `id` shouldn't contain whitespaces.

Comment: Why do you actually need that `id`? You already can refer all those elements by the class.

Comment: I have fixed my mistakes in typing. I do need ID to refer to those elements indyvidualy in Google Tag Manager, however I found out that it is possible to use innerText as a value of events so the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the childnodes until you get to the first textNode that isn't empty to get the text you want. Note also thaat `replace()` only works on first instance found and you probably want to convery to lower case to match your replacements

```js
addIDtoGI()

function addIDtoGI(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.sf-label-radio').forEach(el=>{
     let txtNode = el.childNodes[0];
     while(!txtNode.textContent.trim()){
       txtNode = txt.nextSibling
     }
     el.id = onlyEngLetters(txtNode.textContent);   
     console.log(el.id)
  });
}

function onlyEngLetters(text) {
   return text.toLowerCase()
           .replaceAll("ę","e")
           .replaceAll("ó","o")
           .replaceAll("ą","a")
           .replaceAll("ś","s")
           .replaceAll("ł","l")
           .replaceAll("ż","z")
           .replaceAll("ź","z")
           .replaceAll("ć","c")
           .replaceAll("ń","n")
  
}
```

```html
<label class="sf-label-radio">Name1<span>Some Other Text that I do not need</span><label>
<label class="sf-label-radio">Name2<span>Some Other Text that I do not need</span><label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const addIdToClassByInnerHTML = cls => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + cls);
    elements.forEach(el=>{
        el.setAttribute('id', el.innerHTML);
    });
}
```

note that do not use this function if the element contains child.

if your element contains one or more child(ren), use this:

```js
const addIdToClassByInnerHTML = cls => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + cls);
    elements.forEach(el=>{
        let html = el.innerHTML;
        el.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(sub=>{
            html = html.replace(sub.outerHTML, '');
        });
        el.setAttribute('id', html);
    });
}
```

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/xxqgOEM?editors=1111)

snippets

```js
const addIdToClassByInnerHTML = cls => {
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + cls);
elements.forEach(el=>{
    let html = el.innerHTML;
    el.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(sub=>{
        html = html.replace(sub.outerHTML, '');
    });
    el.setAttribute('id', html);
});
}

addIdToClassByInnerHTML('sf-label-radio');

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.sf-label-radio')[0]);
```

```css
label{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="sf-label-radio">Name1<span>Some Other Text that I do not need</span><label>

<label class="sf-label-radio">Name2<span>Some Other Text that I do not need</span><label>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you define your function but you never *call* it.

In your script, add the "()" to "addIDToGI;": `addIGToGI();`

There's also a typo on `searchButtons.lenght`, it should be `length`.

It **should** resolve your errors.

EDIT: Also, as someone mentionned in the comments, `<lable>` should be `<label>`.

Answer (score 0):

First you must call function with **()** and when using for loop must use variables=>
**for(let i = 0; i < searchButtons.length; i++)** . length is true not lenght.  and of course
**let x = searchButtons[i].innerHTM**L;

and ...